# Why does the output comes undefined?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have two objects named `ball` and `ground` and I'm trying to find the greatest distance between them, but why does the value of `greatest` is always "`undefined`"?

Here's the code:

```
var dt: Array = [];
var greatest = 0;
var i: int;
var j: int;
ball.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bg);
function bg(event: Event) {
    d = Math.sqrt(ball.x - ground.x) * (ball.x * ground.x) + (ball.y - ground.y) * (ball.y - ground.y);

    for (i = 1; i < 1002; i++) {
        dt[i] = d;
    }
    for (j = 1; j < 1002; j++) {
        if (dt[j] > dt[j + 1]) {
            greatest = dt[j];
        } else {
            greatest = dt[(j + 1)];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what that code is good for or what does it supposed to do! However, here's why the value of the `greatest` is always `undefined`:

The first `for` loop, assigns the elements of `dt` array in the range of `1` to `1001`, with the value of `d`!

In every iteration of your second `for` loop, you compare two equal values, thus the `>` comparison fails and the flow executes the instruction inside the `else` statement assigning the `greatest` with the result of `dt[(j+1)]`. In the last iteration (when the `j` is equal to `1001`), however, a same routine carries out, but this time, the expression of `dt[(j+1)]` evaluates to `dt[1002]` which is `undefined` (remember that the "defined" elements reside in the range of `1` to `1001` :)